# Sequence of events that can cause lost money in MultiBit

Tags: multibit, backup, address-generation

If you create a new address in MultiBit, then transferred money to the new address before the wallet was backed up, then your hard drive crashed, will you lose the money?

The first Bitcoin client had 100 addresses, hidden. You could send to a new address and it was most likely already backed up. Does MultiBit do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new receiving address it is written to disk and backed up locally (ie on your disk).

If your disk was destroyed or stolen you would lose your bitcoin yes. This is why we recommend backups on another machine or USB drive.

There is no hidden key pool in MultiBit

Comment: So I guess I should always backup the wallet immediately after I create a new address. Thanks! My backups run automatically but could take 24 hours. Maybe I should create 1-2 addresses for future use so they are already backed up.